# Using read() for reading a file in C

Tags: c

My goal is to read the content of a file and print it to the screen

So, I have a file called "file.txt". I want to read it using the read() function and then print its contents.

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
int file = open("./file.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0777); // added

char buffer[50];
printf("Reading file.txt\n");
int bytes = read(file,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
printf("Bytes read = %d\n",bytes);
if(bytes <=0 ){
  printf("file.txt\n impossible to read\n");   
}else{
  printf("Read - %s \n",buffer);
}

close(file);
```

My code is not working. It returns bytes = -1.

What is wrong with my code?

In my file, I only have a sentence written or a single char. It's that simple just for testing.

Comment: Don't you need to open the file first before reading it? Something like FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors and won't compile.  Please copy and paste your actual code.  In particular, this won't compile:  `read(file.txt,buffer,sizeof(buffer))`  You should also be using `fread` rather than `read`, and of course `fopen` and `fclose`.

Comment: Any book, tutorial or example you come around should have told you that you need to *open* the file first.  It seems you've just heard  something about `read` from somewhere, but didn't bother to learn much more about it, and are just guessing about things and how it works. That's never a good way to learn anything. Study, and study hard.

Comment: Match the calls too: `open` and `close` with `read`, but `fopen` and `fclose` with `fread` (binary file) or `fgets` (text file).

Comment: I am sorry but of course that I opened and closed the file. The problem is that I only added the snippet here that really matters. Sorry for that but opening and closing are working fine.

Comment: Edited with open() and close

Comment: @GratefullyDead "the snippet here that really matters" No. If you do not understand what is going on, and you obviously don't, then you don't know what really matters. Sometimes the particular header files used are very important. Variable declarations are extremely important. For example your code snippet uses `file.txt` in the read call, which we all *KNOW* is completely wrong.

Comment: You still aren't posting a complete program source. But whatever. Did you fail to notice opening the file with `O_WRONLY` and then trying to read from it/

Comment: I know what I meant was that I needed help with that part of the code. The "file.txt" part was my bad. Sorry for that!

Comment: The flag O_WRONLY could be causing the error? I don't get it!

Comment: That's right. Without the flag, it works. Thanks!

Comment: `O_WRONLY` opens a file for *writing only.* Do you see the part you thought was "unimportant to post", has an error? Please see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: When you omit `O_WRONLY` (which is 1) you are left with 0 (which is `O_RDONLY`). That's why it works

Comment: How to use read in POSIX (or how I write it anyway):
https://gist.github.com/zlynx/3d794c89913accfed2de948407bfa515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to open a file if it doesn't exist you also want to write to it i assume so you need to open with both reading and writing permissions

Here is an example of using a loop when we do not know how big the file is (So we aren't reading in one go here).

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[BUFSIZ+1];
    ssize_t n = 0;
    while ((n = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n)) == -1) {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);        
        }        
    }
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        exit(1);    
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

And here is an example of first checking how big the file is and then reading everything in one go

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1); 
    }

    struct stat sb;
    if (stat("file.txt", &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Incase you want to write to file if file is empty
    if (sb.st_size == 0) {
        puts("File is empty we can write to file here");
        // Write here
    } else {
        char *buf = malloc(sb.st_size+1);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((read(fd, buf, sb.st_size)) == -1) {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
        buf[sb.st_size] = '\0';
        if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sb.st_size)) == -1) {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```